# Can I upload images from SQL Server to cloud services and which server is best?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a database for a company and I need to store some images for them. I want to give users the ability to select the image in form I create and then SQL server should upload it to a cloud service directly but I don't know how to do it and which cloud service is best for this job

thanks and regards, Yeki

Answer (score 0):

You will have to elaborate on what you're looking for as there are multiple options avaialble.

1) If you're using Microsoft and are set on Cloud Services, look at the Azure Platform. You're able to store files and manage a database from the cloud and it is very cost effective. They will host your application as well if you need.

2) Are you not able to store the files in the same location the app is being hosted?

3) If the images are relatively small (i.e. less than 200kb), you can save them directly in the database.
You can store larger images, it's just not as efficient, so a file store would be better.